# Calculating material needed for a lamp shade with an allowance for the seam.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, terminology, solid-geometry

I wanted to solve this problem but my English is bad and not familar with tailor stuff....

> A lamp shade is in the form of a frustum of a cone with slant height 7 inches, radii of bases 3 inches and 7 inches respectively. How much material is used in its construction if  0.75 inches is allowed for the ***seam***?

I wanted to solve the problem but **I do not know what is a *seam* is**.

Can somebody just give me a drawing for it so I can solve it.

Thanks!

The answer should be: **221.66 square inches**

This question is from the book: **Solid Mensuration**, Second Edition by Willis Kern and James Bland

Comment: seam.

noun
1.
a line where two pieces of fabric are sewn together in a garment or other article.

Comment: But then it is not clear what is meant because the seam, which is $0.75$ inches long, cannot be the same as the slant height, which is $7$ inches long.

Comment: I suspect the $0.75 inches is width, not length,

Comment: @AdamRubinson: when a *seam* is a line, how can the size be expressed using **square** inches?

Comment: 'Seam' means 'overlap' here. It is the _width_ of the blue line in Adam Rubinson's (deleted) answer.

Comment: @Dominique We can relatively safely assume that the seam is the sewn line traversing up the slant, separating the frustum with an approximately rectangular flap of excess fabric (a hem or "tailor expansion", if you will). The given length would be the width of that hem and we would seek to find its area.

Comment: This is not really a question about mathematics---it is a question about the English language (and is answered by Google https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aseam&oq=define%3Aseam).

Comment: Oh I get it now.

Comment: After consulting with the moderators at [ell.se], this question would also be off-topic there, *unless* you can cite dictionary definitions and explain how those dictionaries are not clearing up your confusion.

Comment: @ Den ji: I understood seam as overlap width 0.25 instead of 0.75 inch you gave to get answer same area you indicated. Could it be a typo by any chance?

Answer (score -3):

Slant length $L= 7", R= 7", r=3" $, with overlap assumed seam width $S= 0.25"$ gives (near to what the answer should be).

$$ \pi L (R+r)+ L ~S= 221.661" $$
With $S= 0.75"$ the area is more, consider for discarding.